# How can I implement hover event on a Vue3 component without mutability?

Tags: typescript, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I'm trying to implement the `hover` event on a custom navbar component and I always see the implementation that way:

```js
<template>
  <nav @mouseover="hover = true" @mouseleave="hover = false" :class="{ open: hover }">
    <!-- ... -->
  </nav>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
defineProps<{hover?: false}>();
</script>
```

However, using vue eslint rules triggers `vue/no-mutation-props` on this implementation.

There's a way to implement hover event and change the `hover` prop value withou mutability?

Comment: Here's the eslint rule description: https://eslint.vuejs.org/rules/no-mutating-props.html#vue-no-mutating-props

Comment: [props should always be one way](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/props.html#one-way-data-flow) which is why they shouldn't ever be mutated by the child component. what's the use case for `hover` being a prop?  how is it used in the parent and why can't it be made a regular ref variable in the child?  if it really needs to be a prop, you would normally emit the new value to the parent and have the parent handle the mutation.

Comment: Oh thank you! I misunderstand the usage of props and refs inside the component! indeed props needs to be passed from parent to child and not only being used inside a component

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution

```js
const { createApp, ref } = Vue;

const MyComp = {
  setup() {
    const hover = ref(false)
    return { hover }
  },
  template: `
  <nav @mouseover="hover = true" @mouseleave="hover = false" :class="{ open: hover }">
    hover: {{hover}}
  </nav>`
}

const App = { 
  components: { MyComp }
}
const app = createApp(App)
app.mount('#app')
```

```css
#app { line-height: 2; }
[v-cloak] { display: none; }
nav { background-color: lightgray; padding: 10px;}
nav.open { background-color: lightblue; }
```

```html
<div id="app" v-cloak>
  <my-comp></my-comp>
</div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
```

Comment: indeeed, i was confusing the idea of components props and components refs